# Running gradle resulting in error on Jenkins

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I'm trying to run a Jenkin's job (which is hosted on AWS).

If i try to run the gradlew command from ssh / command line it works just fine.

But When I try to run the Jenkins job with same commands which I used in commandline then its failing with following error:

Please HelP;

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry using TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry().
> Could not create service of type CachingFileHasher using TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter().
```

Comment: is jenkins running as a different user ?

Comment: the name of the user account is ubuntu.

Comment: i read somewhere that the username of the user account should be jenkins? is it true and that is why this error is occurring?

Comment: no it is not true, what user you login in as when you run gradle from command line? if it is different from ubuntu than you need to make sure they both have same permissions.

Comment: its a root user. I use sudo in order to get the root privileges.

Comment: that is likely to be your problem, I think ubuntu user does not have access to some of the directories/files that gradle is trying to access.

Comment: Try running with `-s` and `-i` or `-d` if `-i` did not provide information to recognize the concrete problem.